# Custom View Scope with SetPropertyActionListener

Tags: spring, jsf

I'm using Spring with a custom view scope to create view scope beans. This works fine until I tried to inject a property using setPropertyActionListener. This works fine if I change the bean to request scope.

This is my view scope impl:

```
public class ViewScope implements Scope {

public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot() != null) {
        Map<String, Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();
        if (viewMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return viewMap.get(name);
        } else {
            Object object = objectFactory.getObject();
            viewMap.put(name, object);
            return object;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public Object remove(String name) {
    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot() != null) {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove(name);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
    // Do nothing
}

public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
    return null;
}

public String getConversationId() {
    return null;
}
```

}

and my JSF:

```
<h:commandLink action="confirm.xhtml">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{quoteHolder.item}" value="#{quote}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: And the question is: why it's not working, I presume? Any error messages on the console? Some stacktrace would be helpfull.